# Loop range check similar values

Tags: vba, excel

Cheers, everyone! The code I wrote doesn't want to do the job I need. What I tried to write has the following meaning: the code needs to look in columns A, B, C and F. Below is an example:

> A5 = home; B5=dog; C5=cat and F5= 50
>
> A6 = home; B6=dog; C6=cat and F6=40
>
> A7 = home; B7=dog; C7=cat and F7= 20

Because we have similar values in column A, B and C --> column F sums up their values. As in this case the total value is 110 (50+40+20) > 100, the cells F5, F6 and F7 need to turn red.

The reason why I am using **range** is because people will copy-paste values in the columns mentioned and I need to code to check all their cells. Can anyone help me with this? All the best!

Thanks in advance!.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Target

    If Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")) Is Nothing Then

        If Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a5:a5000")) And Application.Intersect(cell, Range("b5:b5000")) And Application.Intersect(cell, Range("c5:c5000")) Then
        Sum = Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000"))
            If Sum > 100 Then
                Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Else
                Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If

        End If
Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code as posted cannot even run because you an extra `End If`. Sounds like you need SUMIFS.

Comment: Also your second if can never be true - you need OR not AND

Comment: will have a look now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `Change` event captures the change in a single cell only. If your task is to determine which cells were changed by a user's pasting action you need to capture the selected range using the `Selection_Change` event. But how would you phrase the task if the user selects something from Q4:S40 and pastes it into E4:G40 while you are interested only in F5:F5000? Your example lacks required detail and appears too far from reality to enable a real solution.

Comment: @Variatus - he's looping through Target so that at least shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not only with the specific use of Excel VBA commands, but more essentially with the logic of the code, at various points.

I am posting below code that works, although it has to be adapted to your needs.
It is commented at each point that needs attention (scroll to the right to see the comments).
The ítems are listed here as well, please see the respective locations in comments in the code.

1. The first `If` is not needed. If the following condition is true, this one will never be.
2. This `Intersection` will always be empty, so I used instead a hardcoded `Range`. You should adapt this.
3. Use of auxiliary variables is always encouraged.
4. Again, this `Intersection` will always be empty, so something different is needed. I used instead a `Range` likely similar to what you would like to use.
5. Alternative definition of color.
6. Spurious `EndIf`.

Your logic and code requires significant modification.
The question requires much better definition / clarification.
But this may get you going.

A few notes:

1. Prior to using any function that needs a `Range`, it is typically good practice to check that `Range` is `Not Nothing` (unless you hardcode it and then you know it is not empty). E.g., to use it as an parameter for `Application.Sum`.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Target
    Dim r As Integer
    r = cell.Row
    'If Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")) Is Nothing Then           ' 1. This is not really needed. If the next condition is true, this one will never be.
      If Not (Application.Intersect(cell, Range("A5:C5000")) Is Nothing) Then
        'Sum = Application.Sum(Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")))   ' 2. This Intersection will always be empty...
        Sum = Application.Sum(Range("F5:F7"))                                    ' 2... Using here a hardcoded Range. You should adapt this.
        Dim ctmp As Range                                                        ' 3. Use of auxiliary variables is always encouraged
        'Set ctmp = Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000"))               ' 4. Again, this Intersection will always be empty.
        Set ctmp = Range("F" & CStr(r))
        If Sum > 100 Then
          'ctmp.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)                                  ' 5. Alternative definition of color
          ctmp.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
          'ctmp.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
          ctmp.Interior.Color = vbWhite
        End If
      End If
    'End If                                                                      ' 1...
  Next
  'End If                                                                        ' 6. Spurious EndIf
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks , Sancho.s I adapted your code according to my needs and it works now. Must appreciated!

Comment: @geocc - I'm glad it worked. Perhaps you could post the working code at the bottom of your question, so others can see the difference and understand what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets pull your code apart....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
```

You've declared `cell` as a variable, but not `sum` so the first problem you'll have if you're following good practice and have `Option Explicit` at the top of the module you'll get a **Variable not defined** error.

```
For Each cell In Target
```

Next the loop - the Change event will fire when you change the value in a single cell.  Target will be a single cell - try it:  select the range `B1:B5` and type in the first cell.  The event will fire and `Target.Address` will just contain `$B$1`.  So your loop will only work once.

```
If Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")) Is Nothing Then
```

This just checks that the value you've changed *isn't* in the range F5:F5000.  Surely better to check that it is in the correct range otherwise you better check they haven't entered a value in column XFD and all the columns between as well.

```
If Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a5:a5000")) And Application.Intersect(cell, Range("b5:b5000")) And Application.Intersect(cell, Range("c5:c5000")) Then
```

This will throw an error.  You need to check if it's returning anything in this case.  `Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a5:a5000")) Is Nothing` - `cell` isn't in the range *or* `NOT Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a5:a5000")) Is Nothing` - `cell` is in the range.
Maybe better to use `NOT Application.Intersect(cell, Range("a5:c5000")) IS NOTHING`?
Also, `cell` can't be in column A, B and C at the same time.

```
sum = Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f1:f5000"))
```

This will return the value at the intersection of `cell` and the range `F1:F5000`.  If `cell` isn't in that range it will throw an error.  You've made sure it isn't in that range in the first `IF` statement.

I won't mention the `sum>100` statements as that'll work if the code could get there - not sure what will happen if `sum` is text though.

```
Application.Intersect(cell, Range("f5:f5000")).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

If your cell is in the range `F5:F5000` (which it won't be) then colour the back colour of that cell red, otherwise colour it white.

---

Now that's out of the way - how does the code know there's similar values in column A, B & C?  Why is a cat similar to a dog?  Pretty sure a cat would disagree.  Same with a home - my homes made of bricks and mortar, my dogs made of love, cuddles and faeces.

Why does column F = 50?

So, hopefully I've helped explain what's wrong with the code - just no idea what you want the code to do in the first place.

Comment: Darren Bartrup-Cook, thanks for taking out of your time. Your explanation was very useful. Appreciate!